# aoColumns of datatables are not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am trying to handle the value of aoColumns from other php page. But then it is not coming properly, whereas if I use static value then its working.
My code is like :
 in php page

```
$aoColumn = array("null","null","null","{bSortable: false}");
<input type="hidden" name="aoColumn" id="aoColumn" value="' . implode(",",$aoColumn) . '">
```

in js page

```
var aos = $('#aoColumn').val();
 var ao = (aos)?aos.split(","):[];
 $.each(ao,function(i){
 });
```

and in dataTable declaration:
     "aoColumns":ao

But it is not working.
Please let me know the issue.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I got to know that, in my case `aoColumns` prints `["null", "null", "null", "{bSortable: false}"]` whereas it should be `[null,null,null,Object{bSortable=false}]`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fun one :-) Taken your setup 1:1 (just 3 columns though) :

```
<?
$aoColumn = array("null", "{bSortable: false}", "null");
echo '<input type="hidden" name="aoColumn" id="aoColumn" value="' . implode(",",$aoColumn) . '">';
?>
```

JS

```
var ao = [];
var aos = $('#aoColumn').val().split(',');
for (var i=0;i<aos.length;i++) {
    if (aos[i]=='null') {
        //no need for processing
        ao.push('{ null }');
    } else {
        //remove {, } and whitespace, return array splitted by :
        var s = aos[i].replace('{','').replace('}','').replace(' ','').split(':');
        //create object
        var o = {};
        //here you need to force a real boolean instead of "false"
        o[s[0].toString()]=(s[1]=="false") ? false : true;
        ao.push(o);
    }
}

$('#table').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": ao
});
```

Viola. Datatables parses `ao` correct, the second column is not sortable.

Comment: Thanks a lot davidkonrad. Actually I want to set up a dynamic value for the aoColumns. Now its working properly as I expected. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1):

The way you pass `$aoColumn` to your script is wrong. You should pass it as JSON instead -- and if the JSON is being transferred inside HTML, it needs to be properly HTML-encoded as well:

```
$aoColumn = array(null, null, null, array('bSortable' => false));
echo '<input ... value="' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($aoColumn)).'">';
```

And turn it back into an object with [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var aoColumn = $.parseJSON($('#aoColumn').val());
```

However, I 'm not sure why you want to bother with the hidden field at all. You can pass the configuration to JavaScript directly:

```
<?php $aoColumn = array(null, null, null, array('bSortable' => false)); ?>

<!-- later on.... -->
<script>
    var aoColumn = <?php echo json_encode($aoColumn); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer, but is it not a completely different approach? What if Mausumi not is able / allowed to change the PHP-script?

Comment: @davidkonrad: Then they should say that there are specific restrictions in place. Although I doubt that is the case, since the question says "my code is like...".

Comment: right, but as you can see - some times all we want is just an answer, not a lecture

Comment: @davidkonrad: To each his own :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('[null, null, null, {"bSortable": false}]');
```

Modify your implode function so that your `value="[null, null, null, {\"bSortable\": false}]"`
and then run `JSON.parse()` on the `.val()` to get your settings object.